# How to install the same version of a docker image?

Tags: docker

On machine A I have docker image FOO/BAR installed. How do I query the version of that image, and how do I install the same version to machine B?

Please note that on machine B I don't need the newest available version of FOO/BAR, but the same version as machine A. I don't want to keep local modifications to the image made on machine A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker uses a tag or digest to distinguish between different versions of an image. When specifying neither a tag or a digest, all Docker commands assume that you want to use the default tag `latest`. But you can always be more specific.

Assuming the image comes from a registry `FOO` and is called `BAR`, there are two ways how you can pull the same version of the image: either by tag or by digest. You can only use the tag if you know that it is unique and not reused. This is often the case when using build numbers or Git hashes as tags, but if you want to be absolutely sure, use the digest.

On machine A, run `docker images --digests`. Look for `FOO/BAR` and its digest (starting with `sha:`).

On machine B, run the following command and replace `{digest}` with the digest from machine A:

```
docker pull FOO/BAR@{digest}
```

This is an example how it could look:

```
docker pull FOO/BAR@sha256:e4957dfd892f656ae672dfa03eb7a73f1c47bd24fc95f2231fc5ac91a76092a0
```

This will download the same version that is available on machine A to machine B. Since it comes from the registry, it's a fresh copy without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a tag!**

docker image supports tag, which is usually used as a version number. When building an image, you can specify a tag:

```
docker build -t myimage:v0.1 .
```

Then use the same image is easy:

```
docker run -d myimage:v0.1 entrypoint.sh
```

If you do not specify a tag, and everything works fine. Because docker uses default tag `latest`, which can be annoying when updating and keeping them sync.

`latest` image can change all the time(usually with CI/CD auto-build), so easy container can use different images. If there is not what you expected, **use a tag always!**

Comment: A tag doesn't guarantee that it's the same image. Imagine machine A pulls the tag latest. After that, a new version of the image is pushed to the registry with this tag. If machine B would now pull latest, it would receive a different image than machine A. A tag doesn't help much in this case, because it doesn't guarantee uniqueness. Using a digest is the only safe option in OP's case.

Comment: I'm not building my own image, I have no control over the tags the images have.